# Picture Location Data

Tags: photo-management

When I upload photos from my android phone to a Windows machine the location details are shown under the 'info' or 'details' tab on each picture. When I do this on my Ubuntu 21.04 machine the location detail is missing. I have tried copying the photos from Windows to Ubuntu using a USB stick and location is still missing.
Am I missing something obvious here or is Ubuntu just not equipped to deal with location data.

Comment: This might sound ridiculous - maybe I’ve misunderstood - but if you’ve copied something from windows to Ubuntu, surely you know where you copied them to?

Comment: Are you talking about your file manager? Presumably the info is stored in EXIF data and your file manager of choice either doesn't show that data, or you haven't configured it to do so.  Check the settings of your file manager. You might also be able to inspect EXIF data in your image viewer. You can always switch to another flavor of Ubuntu if you are not satisfied with the one that you're using. Or you could install a different file manager.  GNOME in particular (Including GNOME Files) subscribes to a "less is more" or "worse is better" UI design.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have now found the EXIF detail Nmath refers to and can see the GPS coordinates which no doubt precisely details the exact place the photo was taken. That is what I was looking for and should have seen it before. It is a pity though that as well as the longitude and latitude coordinates it couldn't also just name the place. Maybe I can't expect more but do you know if any other file manager does this? Being a total novice here I have no idea about file managers or indeed which one I am using other than it must be whatever is standard in 21.04.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about the *GPS Location Data* (EXIF) that is embedded in the picture files, Ubuntu handles that just fine.

Here's a crop of a picture displayed in Shotwell showing the lat & lon. (I blurred out some of the digits)

[image]

And this is from the "eye of MATE" image viewer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using GNOME. The location data of each file can be ascertained in two ways -

- Right-click an image file and select Properties from the pop-up window. The location will be mentioned besides the heading 'Parent folder.'
- Select an image file and press Ctrl+L, the location bar at the top will display the path of the directory that contains this file.